# How to only use oh my zsh in Iterm2, and not all other terminals also?

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

After installing oh my zsh and customizing it a little, iTerm2 looks awesome but the default terminal on MacOS looks like crap because it can't load the plugins and I don't want it to. So how can I only use oh-my-zsh on Iterm2?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191780/how-do-i-configure-my-terminal-app-with-bash-and-iterm2-with-zshell-and-oh-my-zs I think here is the same question.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds difficult to do so. Perhaps you can specify your Terminal to open with bash rather than zsh. Then iterm2 will open with zsh (and oh-my-zsh) and terminal will open with bash.

[image]

Comment: isnt it possible to use zsh on terminal too but without ohmyzsh configurations ?

Comment: @Burk you can always run some shell manually. If you wanna use zsh without ohmyzsh, remove `export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh` from you .zshrc file and run it manully in 'shells open with command'